# How not to seek to keyframes

Tags: java, android, video-capture, video-player

I've tried to find a solution to seek frame by frame (not only to keyframes) in my android app.

1. approach: A simple `VideoView` of the `android sdk`:
   Here I've got a `onSeekCompleteListener` of the base class `MediaPlayer` from the `onPreparedListener` of `VideoView` and `pause` the playback right after started it and moved to a preferred position.
   **Problem**: Only seeks to keyframes!
2. approach: `MediaMetaRetriever`:
   I have got something like this:

   ```
   MediaMetadataRetriever retriever;
   long Position;
   ImageView video;
   TextView lbPosition;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       video = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imVideo);
       lbPosition = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.lbPosition);
       bnTake = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bntake);
       retriever.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.vid));

       video.setOnClickListener(new ImageView.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
              Position += 100000;
              Bitmap frame = retriever.getFrameAtTime(Position, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
              video.setImageBitmap(frame);
              lbPosition.setText(String.valueOf(Position));
          }            
       });

       bnTake.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View arg0) {
               Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
               startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, 123123);
           }
       }); 
   }
   ```

When I use `OPTION_CLOSESTS` in `retriever.getFrameAtTime` it gives me a `getFrameAtTime: videoFrame is a NULL` pointer error. When I don't use this option, it goes through keyframes.

Maybe possible solutions:

1. approach: Record video with more keyframes. If I would record the video with an higher `keyframe rate` in my android app, could that be a solution? Is this possible?
2. approach (I haven't tried!): I've heard something of video player 3rd party libraries for android that use `FFMPEG`. Is there any library that can seek while in pause state and update the position for the video on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever)?

Comment: You api perfectly fulfills my needs! I am not someone who thanks everybody at stackoverflow, but this api saved my life!! Just one more question: How to use content uris or videos from raw?

Comment: I'm glad to hear that. I will check back on the content iris and raw resources and get back to you today.

Comment: I added support for setDataSource(Context ctx, Uri uri) You can use this method for content URIs. http://wseemann.github.io/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever/apidocs/wseemann/media/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.html#setDataSource(Context,%20Uri). The library doesn't support raw resources at this time, sorry.