# Is there any audio-playback library that works correct with getCurrentPostition() and seekTo()?

Tags: android, audio, ffmpeg, android-mediaplayer

The MediaPlayer's seekTo() and getCurrentPostition() are working inaccurately and very approximately and this issue is being unsolved by Google for a long time.

I need a good library that can return a precise position of a playback in milliseconds and seek where it needed. But I've tried some like presto, vitamio, ExoPlayer (for this I can't find any documentation how to play from sd card) and yet didn't find a good library.

Using ffmpeg is complex for me and the only java wrapper I've found is only for decoding , not playback .

Please, give me advice how to playback audio and get exact values for getCurrentPostition() and seekTo()

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe it helps: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318835/how-not-to-seek-to-keyframes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318835/how-not-to-seek-to-keyframes)

Answer (score 2):

Check out FFmpegMediaPlayer, it's a ffmpeg library for playback on Android:

https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer

I feel your pain, the built-in MediaPlayer seems to be a steaming pile of garbage with seeking (though I am seeking videos, not audio).

Also be aware that your encoding could be wrong -- double check that the length reported in the codec tags matches the length reported by MediaPlayer.

Comment: To be honest I think I owe a cold beer if you do take it. This is an amazing library, I was using native MediaPlayer and yet all what I have done so far this library had it all and + in a simple way, after rewriting my codes which integrate this library I felt in love with my screen again.